# Convert Ord to Fractional

Tags: haskell

How do I convert an Ord number given by max function into a fractional.
Or how do I convert a number with 2 constraints (x::(Ord a, Fractional a) => a) into an int?

don't worry about RE

```
seemore :: (Fractional a) => RE b -> a -> a
seemore (a:+:b) x = seemore (a) (x) + seemore b x
seemore (a:|:b) x = max (seemore a y) (seemore b z)
   where y = x
         z = x
seemore (Symbol a) x = x
seemore Empty x = 0
seemore (Repeat(a)) x = 1/0
seemore (Plus(a)) x = 1/0
```

in the "seemore :: (Fractional a)" part I need to add Ord a into that constraint, or else it fails. But then I'm stuck with a number that is a fractional and ord though there are no functions that convert that number into an int. Ideally I want a function that converts an ord to a fractional.

Comment: How do you plan to take the maximum of two things if the two things aren't `Ord`? Complex numbers are `Fractional`, but they certainly aren't ordered. What's the max of `-1+i` and `1-i`?

Comment: If we don't need to worry about `RE`, you should remove it from the question. You can write a function of type `Fractional a => a -> a` that demonstrates your problem without it.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to be able to use any possible number type? If you want all the types to be `Int`, just say `Int`.

Answer (score 5):

> Ideally I want a function that converts an ord to a fractional.

Many more things can be ordered than are fractional, eg. `"abcd" < "abce"`, but what is `"abcd" / "abce"`?

> I'm stuck with a number that is a fractional and ord though there are no functions that convert that number into an int.

If you all know is `Fractional` and `Ord`, how do you know a sensible `-> Integer` conversion exists? For instance, consider `Data.Complex Double` (basically just a complex number) - we can add, subtract, divide even (ie. it is `Fractional`) but what would make mathematical sense as an answer for `toInteger (1 + i)`? There isn't a good definition.

It's unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve, but, the closest I can think of is, adding a `RealFrac a` constraint. This would provide you with the functions you want (eg. `truncate`, `round`, `ceiling`, `floor`) for converting to `Integral` types.